# How can I pass the -movflag option to the xuggler API using Java through command line arguments?

Tags: java, xuggler

I'm using the xuggler API to compress video files. I am able to compress the video files successfully with the following code:

```
//These are the arguments to pass to the converter object.
//For H264 transcoding, the -vpreset option is very
//important. Here, presetsFile is a File object corresponding
//to a libx264 video presets file. These are in the
// /usr/local/share/ffmpeg directory.
String[] arguments = {
    inputFile.getAbsolutePath(),
    "-acodec", "libfaac",
    "-asamplerate", "44100",
    "-vcodec", "libx264",
    "-vpreset", presetsFile.getAbsolutePath(),
    inputFile.getParent() + "/" + inputFile.getName() + ".mp4"
}

try {
    //Finally, we run the transcoder with the options we provided.
    converter.run(
        converter.parseOptions(
             converter.defineOptions(), arguments)
    );
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But as per requirements I need to pass the `-movflag` option along with the above argument like this:

```
String[] arguments = { 
    inputFile.getAbsolutePath(),
    "-acodec", "libvo_aacenc",
    "-asamplerate", "44100",
    "-vcodec", "libx264",
    "-movflags","faststart",
    "-vpreset", 
    presetsFile.getAbsolutePath(),
    inputFile.getParent() + "/" 
        + inputFile.getName() +"aaa.mp4"
};
```

But it's giving me the following error:

```
org.apache.commons.cli.UnrecognizedOptionException: Unrecognized option: -movflags
  at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.processOption(Parser.java:379)
  at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.parse(Parser.java:193)
  at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.parse(Parser.java:71)
  at com.nfl.mobile.VideoCompress.Converter.parseOptions(Converter.java:334)
  at com.nfl.mobile.xoggler.Simpleh264Transcoder.transcode(Simpleh264Transcoder.java:39)
  at com.nfl.mobile.xoggler.Simpleh264Transcoder.main(Simpleh264Transcoder.java:24)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: After struggling few days i got the solution.Need to add movflag option code in converter.java class. Here is the code                  OptionBuilder.withArgName("movflags");
  OptionBuilder.hasArg(true);
  OptionBuilder
    .withDescription("video movflag to encode with (e.g. \"faststart\")");
  Option movflag = OptionBuilder.create("movflags");                                   then should add that value to option object like this ==> options.addOption(movflag);